# Google Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol Payload Data json key

Tags: ios, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, payload

I have problem with sending some key in **data** Payload to iOS device

Here's my json to send https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -> @POST

```
{
  "time_to_live": 216000,
  "registration_ids": [
    "device token"
  ],
  "content-available" : true,
  "notification": {
    "body": "Some msg",
    "title": "title"
  },
  "data": {
    "code":11,
    "orderStatus": {
      "status": 1,
      "id": 5102
    }
  }
}
```

Headers in POST request:

```
 Authorization=key=myFirebaseKey
 Content-Type=application/json
```

Problem with key **orderStatus**, in client side I get this key as a String

**orderStatus = "{\"id\":5102,\"status\":1}";**

Can I tell Firebase to send this key as an Object?

Or all keys in data must be simple **key=value** keys?

I mean **value** only string integer etc...?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [downstream JSON message syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) says this about the   key-value pairs in the `data` object:

> The key should not be a reserved word ("from" or any word starting
>   with "google" or "gcm"). Do not use any of the words defined in this
>   table (such as collapse_key).
>
> Values in string types are recommended. You have to convert values in
>   objects or other non-string data types (e.g., integers or booleans) to
>   string.